# Trouble creating an object

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to create an object of the employee class in the main method of my app but it cant find the variables department lastName firstName or salary and im not sure why this is what my statement looks like

```
Employee employee = new Employee( department, lastName, firstName, salary);
```

The employee class looks like

```
package javaapplication14;
public class Employee implements DepartmentConstants, Displayable 
{
    private int department;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(int department, String lastName, String firstName,
        double salary)
    {
        this.department = department;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayText() 
    {
        String displayText = firstName + lastName + salary + department ;
        return displayText;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to show the interfaces its implementing or not but if I do I'll edit my post to include them.
The main method is

```
package javaapplication14;
public class DisplayableTestApp
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Displayable Test application\n");

        // create an Employee object
        Employee employee = new Employee( department, lastName, firstName, salary);

        // display the employee information
        String displayTextEmployee = employee.getDisplayText();
        System.out.println(displayTextEmployee);

        // create a Product object
        Product product = new Product();
        // display the product information
        String displayText = product.getDisplayText();
        System.out.println(displayText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the main method.

Comment: I edited it in to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to create an object of the employee class in the main
>   method of my app but it cant find the variables

It can't find the variables because they don't exist in the scope of your constructor invocation. You have to create and pass the variables to the constructor.

The `Employee` class takes in for the constructor:

```
public Employee(int department, String lastName, String firstName, double salary)
```

So, as an example:

```
Employee employee = new Employee(1, "Smith", "John", 50000);
```

Or:

```
int department = 1;
String lastName = "Smith";
String firstName = "John";
double salary = 50000;
Employee employee = new Employee(department, lastName, firstName, salary);
```

Comment: These variables are in the Employee class and i'm trying to import them in order to create an employee object what would the proper way to do that be? when I create an employee object without the variables I get an error that the method expects an int two strings and a double

Comment: @AlexChapp: These variables are *instantiated* in the Employee class when the proper variables are passed in the parameters of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing the 4 variables into the constructor but you haven't created them yet. It would be a lot easier to keep them straight if you didn't use the same name or something close in so many different places. For instance if you made the class look like this.

```
public class Employee implements Department Constants, Displayable
{
    private int employeeDepartmet;
    private String employeeFirstName;
    private String employeeLastName;
    private double employeeSalary;

    public Employee (int dept, String firstN, String lastN, double pay)
    {
        employeeDepartment = dept;
        employeeFirstName = firstN;
        employeeLastName = lastN;
        employeeSalary = pay;
    }

@Override
public getDisplayText ()
    {
        String displayText = employeeDepartment + employeeFirstName + employeeLastName + employeeSalary;
        return displayText
    }
}
```

Then in your main function include

```
int department = 3;
String firstName = "Joe";
String lastName = "Adams";
double salary = 7.45;

Employee employeeOne = new Employee(department, firstName, lastName, salary);
```

You don't have to use this.department to distinguish between the variables that have the same name, it is easy to see which variable is being referred to since they each have a different name and when your app can't find department, firstName, and lastName, and salary, you know that it isn't referring to employeeDepartment etc.